# File upload issue on Production server when uploading from outside the network

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, file-upload, firewall

We are having issue with a file upload functionality that we just deployed to our production server. That code works fine with our Dev and QA servers but when we deployed it to Production server we are having issues when uploading files from outside the network. It works fine when we do it from inside the network but as soon as we try to upload files from outside the network it doesn't upload anything and don’t give any error as well. Our application is developed in ASP.net 4 and we are using a Silverlight multi-file upload control to do the uploading process. On all the servers we have Windows server 2008 R2 and IIS 7. We have given the full rights to Network Services account on the folder and we are using port 80. Any suggestions on what else to check on the server or with the fire wall because I suspect it’s not the code issue because it’s working fine on all the servers except in one scenario  when we upload files  from outside the network on Production server.

Comment: You could try using Fiddler or F12 tools to view the request and see what the server is responding with (if anything). That may give you a clue. Sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: We tried that but there is not much information related to the error in reponse.

Comment: Is the server and the client on the same domain? Do you have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file on the server? What does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Silverlight component has the ability to resolve and attach to the server end point when deployed in production. This is just as likely to be a network IP address / host name resolution issue as it is to be a security / permission issue.

Comment: andleer, thank you for the response but if that would be the case don't you think it shouldn't work at all? Because it works even on Production when we upload files from inside the network.

Comment: Inside your network is likely to have different paths to the end point and is not a good test of it not working outside your network other than pointing to a firewall or name resolution issue.